# cannot convert float NaN to integer

Tags: python, django

I am trying to upload CSV data in MySQL table but my CSV has some empty columns and when I'm uploading my CSV all data before the empty columns are uploading but after that CSV upload getting a stop

```
for i in range(m * chunksize, (m * chunksize) + chunksize):
    company = pd.isnull(df.loc[i]['company'] or df.loc[i]['name'] or df.loc[i]['observed_sales'] or df.loc[i]['observed_transactions'])
    if company == True : 
          df.loc[i]['company'] = ''
          df.loc[i]['name'] = ''
          y = np.nan_to_num(df.loc[i]['observed_sales'])
          z = np.nan_to_num(df.loc[i]['observed_transactions'])
          df.loc[i]['observed_sales'] = df.loc[i]['observed_sales'].replace('nan', np.nan).interpolate(0.0)
          df.loc[i]['observed_transactions'] = df.loc[i]['observed_transactions'].replace('nan', np.nan).interpolate(0.0)
          Company.objects.update_or_create(company_name=df.loc[i]['company'], company_full_name=df.loc[i]['name'], website_url=df.loc[i]['website'])
          obj = Company.objects.latest('company_id')
          id = obj.company_id
          TransactionDetails_Monthly.objects.update_or_create(company_id=id, observed_sales=y, observed_transactions=z, observed_customers=df.loc[i]['observed_customers'], sales_per_customer=df.loc[i]['sales_per_customer'], txns_per_customer=df.loc[i]['txns_per_customer'], avg_txn_value=df.loc[i]['avg_txn_value'], month=df.loc[i]['month'])
          msg = "Data is inserted successfully"
```

I'm facing this error [cannot convert float NaN to integer]

and I also want to show my models.py

```
class Company(models.Model):
    company_id =  models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True) #ForeignKey
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True)
    company_full_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    company_name_url = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    website_url = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    founded_date =  models.DateField(null=True)       
    founded_date_precision =  models.DateField(null=True)       
    total_funding_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=13, decimal_places=2,  null=True)
    total_funding_amount_currency = models.DecimalField(max_digits=13, decimal_places=2,  null=True) 
    total_funding_amount_currency_usd = models.DecimalField(max_digits=13, decimal_places=2,  null=True) 

class TransactionDetails_Monthly(models.Model):
    transaction_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    company = models.ForeignKey('Company' , on_delete = models.CASCADE, null=True)   #ForeignKey
    month = models.DateField()
    observed_sales = models.IntegerField()
    observed_transactions = models.IntegerField()
    observed_customers = models.IntegerField()
    sales_per_customer = models.FloatField(null=True) 
    txns_per_customer = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    avg_txn_value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=13, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: Which field / line of code is raising the exception? In any case, you need to catch and handle the exception. Either reject the line of the spreadsheet with a message that allows the data to be manually investigated and re-entered, or write a convert-to-integer function that catches ValueError (I presume) and returns a default value such as zero. (A spreadsheet is often treating blank cells as zero).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that there are some empty/Nan values in CSV.

You have to add some check for each value like:

for

```
z = np.nan_to_num(df.loc[i]['observed_transactions'])
```

you can do:

```
if 'observed_transactions' in np.nan_to_num(df.loc[i]:
    if not np.nan_to_num(df.loc[i]['observed_transactions']) == 'NaN':
        z = np.nan_to_num(df.loc[i]['observed_transactions'])
    else:
        z = None
else:
    z = None
```